# I am encountering strange eclipse errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting this strange error messages in eclipse.

I cannot find any error in my class files but eclipse still says there is an error:

[image]

When I try to run my main, this window pops up:

[image]

Finally there is an error message in console:

[image]

When I look at lines 20 and 34 I think the error doesn't make any sense.

[image]

Has anyone encountered simular errors?

I already tried to refresh the project, restart eclipse and search in all 4 class files for errors, but cannot find any.

---

**Edit: maintellotest**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class maintellotest {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(maintellotest.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TelloCameraThread camera = new TelloCameraThread();
        TelloCommander commander = new TelloCommander();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if (s.equals("exit"))
                break;
            else if (s.equals("video") && !camera.isStreamOn())
                startVideoStream(camera);
            else if (s.equals("video") && camera.isStreamOn())
                stopVideoStream(camera);
            else
                System.out.println(s + ": " + commander.sendCommand(s));
        }
        in.close();

    }

    public static void startVideoStream(TelloCameraThread camera){
        logger.info("Starting camera thread");
        camera.start();
    }

    public static void stopVideoStream(TelloCameraThread camera) {
        logger.info("Destroying python exec");
        camera.setStreamOn(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I just could move all my classes into a new project, but I want to know why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide the _entire_ class in question (looks like it's only 38 lines) as text. The actual problem might be a line further up in that file which confuses the compiler. Also note that the exception states that line 34 would be part of the method `startVideoStream()` while your code shows `stopVideoStream()` there, so what's running is _not_ your current code.

Comment: If you have the red `!` in Eclipse, you better look at the "Problems" view (Window->Show View->Problems). It usually has more information. Perhaps your project configuration is incorrect.

Comment: create a new package and move all classes to that package . donot use default java package may be this can be the case.

Comment: Also: [edit] your question and use *text* for your source, not a screen shot.

Comment: @Thomas that's what I already thought, but why does eclipse run other code than displayed?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I have used a screenshot so you don't have to count rows. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks, I have seen there's been an error in my projects build path referring to a not existing jar-file.

Comment: If you see ! red on project you may have buildpath errors mostly unresolved dependencies or multiple jre in the build path will cause this